# I have installed xubuntu and since its first starting it is behaving weird by scratching my screen

Tags: graphics, xubuntu, screen

I have installed xubuntu a few days ago but on first start it behaves weird. It boots up normal, run for a few seconds good and then screen restarts and weird lines come across.

It really irritates me. There seems no problem with my hardware. I've installed Windows previously and it ran perfect without any such problem. I've installed this and loving it but this problem making me nuts! I don't want to leave this OS.

[image: Here is a collage of four screenshots of how my screen looks like after that happens.]

Sometimes some buttons become unclickable and I can't click anything. Sometimes clicking works. Also I've fully updated xubuntu except Firefox. Xubuntu version is 15.10.

My Graphics with inxi:

```
 Card: Intel 82945G/GZ Integrated Graphics Controller
       Display Server: X.Org 1.17.2 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
       Resolution: 1024x768@75.08hz
       GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel 945G x86/MMX/SSE2
       GLX Version: 1.4 Mesa 11.0.2
```

Seems like that isn't showing my video memory. It is 128MB and I have 1GB DDR2 RAM. CPU: Intel Core2Duo.

Comment: You need to post some hardware specs, especially graphics.

Comment: What graphics card do you have and which driver do you use? You can use the following tool to determine both. Install it with `sudo apt-get install inxi` and then copy the output of `inxi -G` and [edit] your question to add it. Thanks.

Comment: @ByteCommander Did it.

Comment: May want to try to [disable SNA accelleration](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2182033).

Comment: @mikewhatever last time i've seen my OS it ran fine. I'll use your solution if i see screen going weird again.

Comment: @mikewhatever What that means when he say "you need to create /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ folder (let it be 20-intel.conf) with next lines:" and then some code lines. Do I need to create a folder? or a file? How should I put those code lines and where? and How to restart Xserver? I don't have a server but a PC. 

That problem won't went away! Just didn't! And also my set resolution won't stay there. It keeps changing back to 1400x900.
And here's the latest beauty - http://i.imgur.com/WBZSKar.png It's the terminal I opened to try to disable XNA accleration.

Comment: This is what "cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep SNA" gives me:

[   770.000] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled: xserver-xorg-video-intel 2:2.99.917+git20150808-0ubuntu4 (Robert Ancell <robert.ancell@canonical.com>)
[   770.000] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled for use with valgrind
[   770.003] (II) intel(0): SNA initialized with Alviso (gen3) backend

Comment: After sometime this also happened - https://youtu.be/JyWNC7oQftY However there was no such problem as long as Windows was there in my computer.

Comment: At least answer my third comment from here going above (excluding this) in short. @mikewhatever